# How can I make the Rails 3 router localize URLs using localization files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, routes, internationalization

What I'd like to be able to do is:

in config/routes.rb

```
resources :posts
```

in config/locale/en.yml

```
en:
  resources:
    posts: "posts"
    new: "new"
    edit: "edit"
```

in config/locale/tr.yml

```
tr:
  resources:
    posts: "yazilar"
    new: "yeni"
    edit: "duzenle"
```

and get

```
I18n.locale = :en
edit_post_path(3) #=> /posts/3/edit

I18n.locale = :tr
edit_post_path(3) #=> /yazilar/3/duzenle
```

I'd also like Rails to match any of these routes anytime and pass the associated locale in the params hash such that when I navigate to `/yazilar` , the request should be routed to the `posts#index` action with the `:tr` locale in the params hash.

Any simple or complex way of doing that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also the **i18n_routing** plugin by Guillaume Luccisano at
http://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing that solves most of those problems
however, it currently lacks translating the action names like `../new` and `../edit`. Guillaume says he will implement that *"soon"*, though.

Update: Action name translating has been implemented in **i18n_routing**. Thanks Guillaume. :)

Answer (score 2):

As the mentioned gems are no longer actively maintained, here are some more recent solutions:

- [gem route_translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator)
- [gem rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes)

both are successors of `translate_routes`

or a more powerfull (and complex) solution:

- [routing-filter](https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter)

Comment: Do they translate the action verbs?

Comment: `route_translator` does translate verbs (new->nuevo in the description). I'm not sure about `rails-translate-routes`. It shows `new: crear` in the translation files, but `rake routes` doesn't show translated verbs (in the documentation, I didn't try)

Answer (score 0):

The translate_routes plugin by Raul Murciano provides some of the features you are asking for:

http://github.com/raul/translate_routes

It only works for Rails 2.3.x as far as I know though. But at least you can either get some ideas or even fork the plugin and make it work on Rails 3 yourself.

Comment: This one uses scopes to identify locales, a `/:locale/:resource/:id` type of URL is not what I want. Sorry.